# sql query to compare data of two table and return those that dont match

Tags: php, mysql

**Table1**

receipt1 - book1

700 -      100

701 -      100

702 -      100

**Table2**

book2    receipt2

100       700,701

When i enter bookno = 100 and click search then it match both table1 and table2 and return result like

**Note :** In  table2 receipt2 column has data in comma exploded form....like 701,702,703

**Scenario 1**

If Table2 Not blank Against entered bookno  then return below result only

702

**Scenario2**

If Table2 blank Against entered bookno  then return
700,701,702

**Scenario3**

If Table2 Contain all value of table1 Against entered bookno  then return

0

```
<?php
   if($_POST && isset($_POST['search']))
    {   

        $result=$db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT master.receipt_no FROM scheme_master AS MASTER 
JOIN book_issue_return AS bir ON master.book_no2 = bir.book_no
WHERE master.book_no2 = :book_no2 AND (master.receipt_no NOT IN (SELECT bir.receiptno FROM book_issue_return AS bir))
');
        $result->bindParam(':book_no2',$_POST['book_no']);
        $result->execute(); 
        $data1 = $result->fetchAll();
        $coupons = array(); 
        foreach($data1 as $row)
        {    
            $receipt[] = $row['receipt_no'];            
        }   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
  SELECT `t1`.* FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 `t2`
    ON `t1`.Book != `t2`.Book
```

Comment: thanks for rply but query dont get proper result...  i already said i want those data which is not available in table2 .  for ex - - If a,b,c are in table1 and only a,c is present in table2 so b is not present in table2.....then i need to echo only b... and if there are no data present in table2 then display all  a,b,c....

Comment: I change my question for clear under standing what i want... plz Read ..and help me ..thanks for your rply again..

Comment: @ashokawachat I don't find your question clear at all.

Comment: I only need to match receipt column of both table, and if data in receipt column of table1 are present in receipt column of table2  then not display else display all data other wise display filtered data which  is not present in table2